# XSLT/Xpath -- sum function performance

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, saxon, xslt-3.0

I often use this xpath `sum(preceding::*/string-length())`

It does what I need it to do (provides a character count of all text up to this context in the XML file).

Problem: it is slow.

Is there a different built in function that I should be using instead?  Or an extension?

**UPDATE:**

Based on Michael Kay's comment, I explored XSLT 3.0 `<accumulator>`. It was my first try with 3.0 (I had to update OxygenXML to make it work). I haven't fully adapted it to my needs, but initial test below shows promise.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" />

<xsl:accumulator 
    name="f:string-summ"
    post-descent="f:accum-string-length"
    as="xs:integer"
    initial-value="0">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule 
        match="text/*" 
        new-value="$value + string-length()"/>
</xsl:accumulator>

<xsl:template match="text/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="f:accum-string-length()" />
</xsl:template>
```

Off topic: Stack Overflow needs an "XSLT-3.0" tag.

Comment: Which Xslt parser/compiler do you use?

Comment: For this one..I use Saxon HE, from the command line.

Comment: Can you give an indication of the size of your xml, current timings and target timing?

Comment: I run an identity transform that sets attributes a certain locations in the file (based on size of the text). The template does nothing else. It takes 3 minutes 30 seconds to do a 5 MB xml file. I don't really have a 'target' ...just seems to me that 3 minutes indicates I should reassess what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call this function on every node, then you stylesheet performance will be O(n^2) in the number of nodes.

The function is incorrect anyway. The preceding axis gives you your parent's preceding siblings and also the children of your parent's preceding siblings, so the string length of your cousins is being counted more than once.

Try defining a memo function something like this:

```
<xsl:function name="f:preceding-string-length" saxon:memo-function="yes">
  <xsl:param name="n" as="element()"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="sum(ancestor::*/preceding-sibling::*[1]/(f:preceding-string-length(.) + string-length(.)))"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Or use an XSLT 3.0 accumulator, which amounts to much the same thing.

Comment: The XSLT 3.0 accumulator looks like a graceful solution. I found the W3 spec and tried it out. OxygenXML with SaxonPE 9.5.0.2, the error message "Unknown system function accumulator" came up. What I read indicated that Saxon should have accumulator...is it live?

Comment: Saxon 9.5 implements accumulators as described in the July 2012 draft of XSLT 3.0. The design has changed a little in the Dec 2013 draft.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `sum` function is slow, the navigation to all preceding elements and the computation of the string length of all contents is expensive. As for optimizing it, which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use?

Comment: Saxon allows you to profile a stylesheet, see http://saxonica.com/documentation/html/using-xsl/performanceanalysis.html. Whether that helps for your code I am not sure. In your comment to Rene you also indicate your complete stylesheet is short so consider showing it in your question, together with an input sample showing the structure you need to process, then maybe someone else can make a suggestion on how to optimize the XSLT for Saxon or in general.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Martin. Tried it..and it told me the obvious (he said with the priceless wisdom of hind sight) that Michael Kay brought up.. see his reply. Now I realize with the size of some of my documents, from 1 MB to a max of 70 MB, I need an approach that benefits from stream processing.